# Check for user meta data at Login

Tags: users, login, user-meta

On my website, users have a meta data attribute that is set to either true or false depending on whether they have confirmed their email address or not. I'm trying to not let them log in if they have not confirmed their email but let them log in if they have.

To accomplish this, I have added the following code to my functions.php file. However, with this in place, it won't let anyone log in. Where is the mistake?

```
<?php
function isUserActivated($user){
    $userStatus = get_user_meta($user, 'account_activated', true);
    $login_page  = home_url('/login/');
    if($userStatus == 0){
        wp_redirect($login_page . "?login=failed");
        exit;
    }
}

add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'isUserActivated');
```

Comment: you need to add 1 in account_activated meta value for existing users

Comment: I am doing that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the filter `wp_authenticate_user` you get the user object you need to use the user ID to get the user meta

```
function isUserActivated($user){
    $userStatus = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'account_activated', true);

    // for testing $userStatus = 1;
    $login_page  = home_url('/login/');
    if($userStatus == 0){
        wp_redirect($login_page . "?login=failed");
        exit;
    }

    return $user;
}

add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'isUserActivated');
```

But I think better use the action `wp_authenticate` because its run before the `authenticate` filter.

```
function isUserActivated($username){

    // First need to get the user object
    $user = get_user_by('login', $username);
    if(!$user) {
        $user = get_user_by('email', $username);
        if(!$user) {
            return $username;
        }
    }

    $userStatus = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'account_activated', true);

    //for testing $userStatus = 1;
    $login_page  = home_url('/login/');
    if($userStatus == 0){
        wp_redirect($login_page . "?login=failed");
        exit;
    }

}

add_action('wp_authenticate', 'isUserActivated');
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: @PhilippK Notice that you need to remove the `$userStats = 1;` I did it for testing.

Comment: I did remove it. However, I was getting excited too soon. This code lets users log in even if they haven't confirmed their email. Edit: Nevermind, forgot to change the hook. Works fine now